# Taking decision on command line parameters in a cocoa applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have my Cocoa Application, which will be called with or without parameters in the command line.

I would like to take decisions over the parameters received on the application, ie, if a special parameter is received I would like to trigger an action on it.
Is there anyway for doing this??

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Sure, your program has a `main()` function like any C program.  The default one that comes with a new Cocoa project just calls `NSApplicationMain()`, but you can do other actions if you'd like.

If you want to easily access the command line information from elsewhere in your program, you can use `_NSGetArgv()`, `_NSGetArgc()`, `_NSGetEnviron()`, and `_NSGetProgname()`.  They're declared in `crt_externs.h`:

```
extern char ***_NSGetArgv(void);
extern int *_NSGetArgc(void);
extern char ***_NSGetEnviron(void);
extern char **_NSGetProgname(void);
```

Here's <strike>a [blog post](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/07/access-argc-and-argv-from-anywhere.html) about these functions, and</strike> a link to the `NSApplicationMain` [documentation](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSApplicationMain).

Comment: +1 I think that's the first time I've ever seen anything return a `char***`

Comment: @Dave It makes more sense as a CharPtrArrayPtr, which is still quite a mouthful but looks less Perlesque.

Comment: @Jeremy thinking of it as a "pointer to an array of strings" helps me understand it.  I'm primarily confused about why it doesn't just return a `char**` tho...

Comment: @Dave, So that you can modify argc and argv directly, I would guess.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to access the `NSArgumentDomain` in user defaults:

```
NSDictionary *const args = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                             volatileDomainForName:NSArgumentDomain];
```

This will handle arguments of the form `-NSZombieEnabled YES`. Other forms of arguments (such as `-NSZombieEnabled=YES`) might be ignored; I haven't tested or looked at the source.